# why docker is failing to create container when initialized

Tags: docker, server, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to install Docker via Powershell on Server 2016.  I'm trying to run hello-world to prove it works, however, I'm getting a `failed to start` error.  See below:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
9bb5a5d4561a: Extracting [==================================================>]     985B/985B
C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe: failed to register layer: failed to start service utility VM (applydiff ad79c7efb8c389e63a818d2e0ec990366e4175190de84c66d37d7e3ee16ed59f): con
tainer ad79c7efb8c389e63a818d2e0ec990366e4175190de84c66d37d7e3ee16ed59f_svm encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows system call: The data is invalid. (0
xd) extra info: {"SystemType":"container","Name":"ad79c7efb8c389e63a818d2e0ec990366e4175190de84c66d37d7e3ee16ed59f_svm","Layers":null,"HvPartition":true,"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":
"C:\\Program Files\\Linux Containers","LinuxInitrdFile":"initrd.img","LinuxKernelFile":"bootx64.efi"},"ContainerType":"linux","TerminateOnLastHandleClosed":true}.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\docker.exe run --help'.
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to run a windows-based container - just to see if that works?

Comment: Yes.  that's the hello-world I was recommended to test with.

Comment: But the error message is about a Linux container - maybe you should switch to windows containers in the context menu of the Docker tray-icon

Comment: have you got a solution for this? I have the same problem